# Django: Create manualy session cookie and authenticate later with it

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-sessions, http-token-authentication

I am using Django-Rest-Framework with token authentication.
In my Android App I want to open a webview and display some content from a view which needs authentication.

Because of this I wrote a rest call to fetch a session id.

/rest/getsessionid/ => looks like that:

```
from django.contrib.sessions.backends.db import SessionStore

class GetSessionKeyView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            s = SessionStore()
            s.create()
            return Response({'sessionid': s.session_key})
        return Response({'notauthenicated': True})
```

Unfortunately the returned sessionid is not working. Why?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found a way.

```
class GetSessionKeyView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            if 'HTTP_COOKIE' not in request.META or request.META['HTTP_COOKIE'] == '':
                login(request, request.user, backend='django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend')
                return Response({
                    'sessionid': request.session.session_key
                })
            else:
                return Response({'ERROR': 'Cookies not allowed'})
        return Response({'notauthenicated': True})
```

You have to login again first to create a session.

EDIT:
Don't forget to block cookies to protect this from CSRF attacks.